.readmem for a file to an address always says load is incomplete
I have dumped memory location from say memory location 0x10000 to 0x20000 in a process to a file. I have a crash dump of the same process and now on windbg I want to write this memory to the specified location so that I can use this data while debugging.
I had thought that I would be able to do it via .readmem(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-readmem--read-memory-from-file-) but it does not work.
The command I use is
.readmem C:\path\to\file\containing\memory 0x10000 0x20000

The file gets read but get an error
Unable to write memory at 0x10000, load is incomplete

How can I resolve this ?

which kind of dump you're working with (user-mode; kernel; full kernel)? Is the memory range already mapped (check with !address or !vprot)? Does the actual inverse operation works (.writemem on the same range)? I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure .readmem will only write onto existing memory and does not allocate anything, so if the memory range is not already there, you can't do much.

This is a usermode dump. The range is already mapped, I tried doing .writemen - that worked, but on the same address space .readmem did not work

I did a quick test on a user-mode process dump and it works if the memory is mapped, but I get the same error message  as you if the range (or part of the range) is not mapped. Can you show us the !vprot and !address outputs on the base address of the range? (and maybe !vadump  output for the addresses of the range). Just to be sure that the whole range exists. If it does, then there's a problem with windbg.

Is it possible that you are off by 1 byte? What about .readmem C:\path\to\file\containing\memory 0x10000 0x1FFFF?
